# Highlighting the selected button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to toggle the parameters of my `activebackground` and `activeforeground` on my button. However, when trying to change the background color and text font after a button is selected, and resetting these settings back to how they were before, if any another button is clicked and once again the clicked button background color and font doesn't change.

[image]

For example in the above screenshot, "Conversation History" is selected so its in grey color with bold font, and all other menu items are in normal font. If I click on "Important", then that "Important" button becomes grey and bold . The code to render the menu is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def abc:
  #this part is not running 

def ResponsiveWidget(widget, *args, **kwargs):
    bindings = {'<Enter>': {'state': 'active'},
                '<Leave>': {'state': 'normal'}}

    w = widget(*args, **kwargs)

    for (k, v) in bindings.items():
        w.bind(k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

    return w


button1 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='abc',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat',
    )
button1.place(x=0, y=50)

button2 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='xyz',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat',command=lambda: abc
    )   #abc is not calling
button2.place(x=0, y=80)

root.mainloop()
```

new code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

selected_button = None
last_bg = None

def abc():
    print("abc")  #Not executing this part

def change_selected_button(button):
    global selected_button, last_bg
    if selected_button is not None:
        selected_button.config(bg=last_bg)
    selected_button = button
    last_bg = button.cget("bg")
    button.config(bg="orange")

def ResponsiveWidget(widget, *args, **kwargs):
    bindings = {'<Enter>': {'state': 'active'},
                '<Leave>': {'state': 'normal'}}

    w = widget(*args, **kwargs)

    for (k, v) in bindings.items():
        w.bind(k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

    return w


button1 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='abc',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat',
    )
button1.place(x=0, y=50)
button1.config(command=lambda button=button1: change_selected_button(button))

button2 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='xyz',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat',command=abc
    )  
button2.place(x=0, y=80)
button2.config(command=lambda button=button2: change_selected_button(button))



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def abc():
    print("abc")

def change_selected_button(button):
    abc()
    global selected_button
    if selected_button is not None:
        selected_button.config(bg="white")
    button.config(bg="light blue")
    selected_button = button

root = tk.Tk()
selected_button = None
for i in range(5):
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me")
    button.pack()
    button.config(command=lambda button=button: change_selected_button(button))
root.mainloop()
```

It uses a global variable `selected_button` that has the blue background. When a new button is pressed the button in `selected_button` is reset and the new one is put in the variable.

This is how you would implement it in your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

selected_button = None
last_bg = None

def abc():
    print("abc")

def change_selected_button(button):
    abc()
    global selected_button, last_bg
    if selected_button is not None:
        selected_button.config(bg=last_bg)
    selected_button = button
    last_bg = button.cget("bg")
    button.config(bg="orange")

def ResponsiveWidget(widget, *args, **kwargs):
    bindings = {'<Enter>': {'state': 'active'},
                '<Leave>': {'state': 'normal'}}

    w = widget(*args, **kwargs)

    for (k, v) in bindings.items():
        w.bind(k, lambda e, kwarg=v: e.widget.config(**kwarg))

    return w


button1 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='abc',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat',
    )
button1.place(x=0, y=50)
button1.config(command=lambda button=button1: change_selected_button(button))

button2 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='xyz',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat'
    )   #abc is not calling
button2.place(x=0, y=80)
button2.config(command=lambda button=button2: change_selected_button(button))

button3 = ResponsiveWidget(
    tk.Button,
    root,
    text='test',
    fg='black',
    activebackground='#B7E3F9',
    activeforeground='black',
    highlightthickness=0,
    relief='flat'
    )   #abc is not calling
button3.place(x=0, y=110)
button3.config(command=lambda button=button3: change_selected_button(button))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. @TheLizzard

Comment: I used this but the function that needs to be run by clicking on the button is not working. i meant the command we give inside the button is not working. only the button.config command is working. please have a look at the updated que and suggest. @TheLizzard

Comment: @Jung-suk Does it give you an error? Are you using `lambda button=button: change_selected_button(button)`?

Comment: No but as in the above example it doesn't call function abc if i click the button. @TheLizzard

Comment: @Jung-suk you missed the brackets. Change it to `command=lambda: abc()`

Comment: No, i am calling the frame there, just gave you a example. the code am using is command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NEWpage) where NEWpage is the frame. @TheLizzard

Comment: @Jung-suk I edited my answer. Can you please try the last piece of code that I posted?

Comment: I have added in the similar way in my code but still not able to execute the button command (abc). added the new code please have a look. @TheLizzard

Comment: @Jung-suk Add `abc()` at the start of the `change_selected_button` function. I changed my answer with that change.

Comment: Thank you. @TheLizzard